# Properties of convolutions w.r.t. continuity and partial differentiability

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, convolution, book-recommendation, online-resources

Is there some good summary of properties of convolutions available out there? I'm interested in continuity and partial differentiability topics, like, when exactly do we have $f*g$ is continuous at $x$ if $g$ is, when do we have $\partial_j(f*g)(x)$ exists and equals $f*\partial_j g(x)$, etc.?

Edit: I postet an answer with all conditions I could derive for myself so far.

Comment: Have you seen the wiki article?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to see if there is some more detailed account with premises like if $f$ is $L^1_{\rm loc}$ (locally integrable) and $g$ is $C^1_c$ (continuously differentiable with compact support) then $\partial_j f*g$ exists anywhere and equals $f*\partial_j g$.  (This is one of the cases I managed to derived for myself but maybe there are more?)

Comment: Are these properties not readily available from the properties for multiplication and addition?

Answer (score 0):

These are the conditions I (think I) could prove to be sufficient...

...for $f*g\in C^0$:

- $f\in L^1$ and $g\in C^0$ is bounded.
- $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}$ and $g\in C^0_c$.

...for $\partial_j(f*g)(x)$ exists and equals $f*\partial_j g(x)$ (assuming $\partial_j g$ exists everywhere and ${\rm dom}(f*g)$ contains some line segment around $x$ in direction $j$):

- $f\in L^1$ and $\partial_jg$ is bounded.
- $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}$ and $\partial_j g$ is bounded with compact support.